# KVM Switch lags when re-connecting to Linux

Tags: keyboard, hardware, mouse

I have this [IOGear GCS22U 2 Port KVM Switch](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.yVaacmbe608w8zX7zIskGQHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1) which I use to switch between my Manjaro machine (Linux manjaro 5.10.56-1-vfio-lts) and my Windows 10 machine. I am using a Corsair K95 RGB Keyboard and a Logitech G403 HERO mouse.

When switching to the Windows machine, it detects and uses the keyboard instantly. While my Linux system detects it, lets run for 1/2 a second, reconects, repeats this twice and then runs like normal. I am wondering is there a way I can have Linux do this reconnect only once and be instant? Something along the lines as keeping the hardware configuration loaded at all times?

This affect appears to be on the mouse, as the cursor does this connect/disconnect effect. Whereas the keyboard does not allow use until this cycle is done (2 seconds).

---

`Dmesg -w` last few lines of output that finish with the keyboard/mouse working after a (re)connect with KVM switch:

```
[23017.065347] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 22
[23017.261618] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 23
[23021.531242] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[23021.737486] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b11, bcdDevice= 2.04
[23021.737490] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[23021.737492] usb 3-1: Product: Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard 
[23021.737493] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Corsair
[23021.737494] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1901F044AE3B94035375958DF5001946
[23021.776179] input: Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B11.0035/input/input169
[23021.776460] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0035: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard ] on usb-0000:11:00.3-1/input0
[23021.789240] input: Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard  Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B11.0036/input/input170
[23021.789369] input: Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard  Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B11.0036/input/input171
[23021.789419] input: Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B11.0036/input/input172
[23021.789469] input: Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B11.0036/input/input173
[23021.789542] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0036: input,hiddev98,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard ] on usb-0000:11:00.3-1/input1
[23021.789595] usbhid 3-1:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[23021.931587] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[23022.134494] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c08f, bcdDevice=45.01
[23022.134498] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[23022.134500] usb 3-2: Product: G403 HERO Gaming Mouse
[23022.134501] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[23022.134503] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 097A39633530
[23022.169133] input: Logitech G403 HERO Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C08F.0037/input/input174
[23022.169370] hid-generic 0003:046D:C08F.0037: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech G403 HERO Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:11:00.3-2/input0
[23022.178445] input: Logitech G403 HERO Gaming Mouse Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:046D:C08F.0038/input/input175
[23022.241635] input: Logitech G403 HERO Gaming Mouse Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:046D:C08F.0038/input/input176
[23022.241697] input: Logitech G403 HERO Gaming Mouse System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:046D:C08F.0038/input/input177
[23022.241797] hid-generic 0003:046D:C08F.0038: input,hiddev99,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech G403 HERO Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:11:00.3-2/input1
[23023.691748] input: ckb1: Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard vKB as /devices/virtual/input/input180
[23023.692018] input: ckb1: Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard vM as /devices/virtual/input/input181
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue may be related to Linux needing to load device drivers whenever you switch your KDM to Linux. To check this, do the following:

Open a terminal. Enter `dmesg -w`. This program will display logs of all devices being enabled and disabled. (Try inserting a USB-drive or similar and see what happens).

Now you have the tool to really see what happens when you perform the KVM-switching. Hopefully you will see one or more drivers being loaded and unloaded. If so, you need to see if you can have these drivers permanently loaded in the kernel. There are several ways to do this, and some quick googling should at least push you in the right direction.

This could be a good start:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858313/want-to-permanently-mount-kernel-driver-into-syste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858313/want-to-permanently-mount-kernel-driver-into-system)m